# Displaying Thumbnails in a row in Django Templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

im using the thumbnail feature of the bootstrap. im displaying them dynamically. But i want to display four thumbnails in a row. how can i do that??? This is the code. This displays the thumbnail one below the other. but i want four in a row. Im creating the thumbnails dynamically. Im very new to Bootstrap.

```
    {% for obj in q2 %}

{{q2.count}}
{{forloop.counter}}
        <tr>
            <td>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <!-- <div class="span4"> -->
<ul  class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
<br>
<br>

    <div  class="thumbnail" style="width:425%;margin-left:20px;height:420px" >
      <img  data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
      <p> <b> {{obj.op_title}} </b></p>     
     <p><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i> <span class="label label-success">{{obj.op_status}}</span></p>
          <p><i class=" icon-user"></i> {{obj.op_positions}} Vacancies</p>
          <p><i class=" icon-map-marker"></i> {{obj.op_location}}</p>
<p><i class="icon-tasks icon-blue"></i> {{obj.op_qualification}} </p>
<p> <i class="icon-star icon-blue"></i> {{obj.op_experience}} Years </p>


<p><i class="icon-calendar icon-blue"></i> {{obj.op_effective_from.day}}-{{obj.op_effective_from.month}}-{{obj.op_effective_from.year}} - {{obj.op_effective_to.day}}-{{obj.op_effective_to.month}}-{{obj.op_effective_to.year}} </p>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">



     <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#{{obj.op_id}}">
  <i class="icon-book"></i>      Job Description
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="{{obj.op_id}}" class="accordion-body collapse ">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
     {{obj.op_desc}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">

      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#{{obj.op_test_type}}">
       Skills Required
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="{{obj.op_test_type}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
       {{obj.op_skill_required}}
      </div>

    </div>

</div>


 <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#{{obj.op_experience}}">
       Skills Preferred
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="{{obj.op_experience}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
 {{obj.op_skill_preferred}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#{{obj.op_desc}}">
       Selection Criteria
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="{{obj.op_desc}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
    {{obj.op_selection_criteria}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>


  <div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url editRow  obj.op_id  %}">Edit</a>
<a class="btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this Opening!!!!');"  href="{% url deleteRow  obj.op_id  %}">Delete</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>





{% endfor %}
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have posted the code above!!

Answer (score 0):

In your css give the images a width;
example

```
#divname img
{
 width:148px;(the size you want )
 height:120px;
}
```

now the images always have the size of 150x120

then set float:left;

the images will load after each other.
you can set

```
#divname img
{
 width:148px;(the size you want )
 height:120px;    
 margin-top:2px;
 margin-right:1px;
 margin-left:1px;
}
```

so there is a small room between the images.

if the div they are in is 600 px there will be 4 images.
you can calculate by (img incl border 150px) 600/150=4 images

I hope this is the answer you were looking for cause the question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Following bootstrap documentation http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails you can display thumbnails like this using grid column sizes `.span3`.

Here you can fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/GgSRN/1/

Your dynamically added item should have code like this:

```
<li class="span3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="myimg" alt="myimg">
    </a>
</li>
```

After each four rows you must end your list and start new one:

```
</ul>
<ul class="thumbnails">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: But having only one <ul class> . Thing is im displaying dynamically. I have posted the code above.

Comment: the images arent working in your example you need to plase the url before it exampl http://www.twitter.com  but i still dont get the problem in the fiddelt there are 4 img files (not working but url) in a row.